# CSS two column layout with fluid height 100%

Tags: html, css

### [image: LAYOUT]

This is my layout - I use this for 2 pages.
I need to be full height (100%) and flexible height in same time.
Red block is empty, only a title/subtitle and full bg (cover) image.

In right side I have small text for first page, and a lot of text for 2nd page, this is why I need to be fluid.

I tryied more methods but I can't make it work.. and I don't want to use js - only pure css2.

Can someone help me? thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your code, preferably with a http://jsfiddle.net/ or other example.

Comment: This is the page, as you can see the bottom of right side id hidden and I need to scroll it [link](http://dev.template-tuners.com/nvt-default-theme/register)

Answer (score 3):

One possibility to achieve what you want would be to use `display:table` & `display:table-cell`:

```
#content {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

#left, #right {
    width: 50%;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39pkH/)

You could also work with `flex-box`.

[Flexbox guide](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score -1):

It will work if you  want change the height of .top and .bottom remember that change the value of var heighs this is (.bottom .top) height
Java script (jquery)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.designerbh.com/index_files/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
setInterval(function(){
    var heights=$("body").height();
    var heights=heights-100;
    console.log(heights);
    $(".red ,.gray").css({'height':heights});
},100);
</script>
```

Html

```
<body style='margin:0px'>
<div class='top'>

</div>
<div class='red'>

</div>
<div class='gray'>

</div>

<div class='bottom'>

</div>
</body>
```

Css

```
<style>
.top{
float:left;
width:100%;
height:50px;
background:black;
color:white;
}
.red{
float:left;
width:50%;
height:100%;
background:red;
}
.gray{
float:left;
width:50%;
height:100%;
background:#ccc;
}
.bottom{
float:left;
width:100%;
height:50px;
background:black;
color:white;
}
</style>
```

Comment: thanks, but I said "and I don't want to use js - only pure css"

Comment: only with pure css will be not possible, bootstrap use js

Comment: js will make the site "responsive" only  if you use @media screen but you have to make a style css for any pixel

Answer (score -2):

I just recommend you using Bootstrap and you dont need to be worried about - Check out their griding getbootstrap.com